# Save multiple entities in one transaction

Tags: entities, performance

We have a custom API endpoint that handles data for multiple users. Unfortunately, we are having a performance issue because every time we save a user entity, the save operation takes 3-4 seconds to complete. Obviously, this is less than ideal, as 10 users will take 30-40 seconds to complete the whole request...

Is there a way to save multiple entities at once (like you can load multiple at once) or is this just another poor Drupal performance issue that we have to live with?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no method for that in core; does the user entity have a lot of fields in your site? Do other entities (different types like node) with a similar number of fields take the same sort of time to save? Are you measuring the full request at 3-4 seconds or have you profiled the user save op specifically at that length? If the former you should be able to deduct a second or two of that from the estimate for each entity as that'll be one-time request overhead

Comment: depends on what you consider "a lot of fields", we have about 80 fields on our user object. In this particular endpoint though, we are updating only 5 of those fields: 2 multiple value references, and 3 multiple value text fields.

Comment: This is just the user save. It takes about 3-4 seconds for `JSON::decode($request->getContent)` to run so that I can work with the data (which is horrendous), then < 1 second to do all my work, then another 3-4 seconds to save the user. So the time it takes to process users is ` 3 seconds + 3 seconds per user`.

Comment: Yeah that's a lot of fields, but actually in theory that shouldn't matter (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/234475/2800). Best advice I can give it to profile the save op and find out where the time is being spent - it might not be database, which would hopefully give you other threads to follow to improve it, but either way you'd know

Comment: The save operation itself takes 3-4 seconds.

Comment: I meant [profile it a bit more scientifically](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), that'll show you where the time is really being spent. If you're lucky your hosting provider might have something like New Relic available